# Window not found exception comes when switchTO().Window("windowname") is used

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium webdriver for Automation in c#, In the web page I have a button,when that is click new IE pop up gets opened, now i want the webdriver to continue the clicks for that new IE window pop up;

[Note:- The Child IE pop up is complete new .aspx page the window name of that i Checked by doing View Page source after right click and that is `window.open("../Reports/MidWayReport.aspx");`]

after a button click i tried following code.

```
webDriver.SwithTO().Window("windowname");
```

but that is generating "No window found exception.

Comment: The code seems to be OK. The above code should work. Is the name of window correct? Can you please check again

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a timing issue - try waiting a couple of seconds before trying to switch to the window.

Comment: Np i increased the wait but it is not timing issue

Answer (score 0):

It's either a timing issue or you haven't named the window.  I think by default all new windows that aren't specifically named get the name _Blank.  That may have changed as it's been years since I've looked at that across multiple browsers.  However, there is an easier solution just name the window.

```
window.open("../Reports/MidWayReport.aspx", "MyWindowName");
```

Then you can do something like this

```
webDriver.SwitchTo().Window("MyWindowName");
```

This used to be set by a link that opened a popup like this

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com" target="MyNewWindowName">Open Window</a>
```

However since you are doing this via javascript I provided the way to do that first.  Here is a link to explain: http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/JSwindows.html